# Connecting Fault tolerant Tibco queue from C#

Tags: c#, ssl, tibco-ems

We are trying to **connect to Tibco queue via SSL for consuming messages** using C#. For connection to work via SSL, we need to **provide the HostName for tibco server using method: EMSSSL.SetTargetHostName**.

This method is accepting only one host name so how can we set the host name in case of fault tolerant Tibco queue setup because in that case we might have more than one Tibco hosts and we need to connect to the active host.

> How can we get the active host name that we can specify in the method:
>   EMSSSL.SetTargetHostName? or is there any way using which we can avoid the  host name verification from C#?

Comment: This is best suited for their support